# pytest don't persist class instance across unit tests

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I'm using pytest to make assertions on a value created by a function inside a class that writes to and returns an attribute of the class. The attribute value persists across two unit tests. How can I get a fresh instance of the class in the second unit test?

```
from dataclasses import asdict

from package.someclass import SomeClass


def test_method_a_one():
    class_instance = SomeClass()
    result = asdict(class_instance.method_a("a")[0])
    assert result["string"] == "a"


def test_method_a_two():
    class_instance = SomeClass()
    result = asdict(class_instance.method_a("b")[0])
    assert result["string"] == "b"
```

When running `pytest tests`

```
tests/test_method_a.py:15: AssertionError
=================================================================================================== short test summary info ===================================================================================================
FAILED tests/test_method_a.py::test_method_a_two - AssertionError: assert 'a' == 'b'
```

full code: https://github.com/michaelhochleitner/pytest_test

Comment: You would usually use pytest fixture scopes here but the thing is you're using `dataclass` which acts like a singleton.

Comment: Can I use pytest fixture scopes if I use regular classes for Result and ResultContainer?

Comment: If you use regular classes, scopes won't even be needed here, your test should work as expected

Comment: I changed the dataclasses to regular classes and use a fixture to inject the class under test. I still get the same output. See https://github.com/michaelhochleitner/pytest_test/tree/regular_classes_and_fixture.

Comment: It's because you have a class attribute in `ResultContainer`, you should have an instance attribute here. See https://dzone.com/articles/python-class-attributes-vs-instance-attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As RobinFrcd pointed out, you have to convert `ResultContainer.result_list` from a class attribute to an instance attribute like this:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class ResultContainer:
    """SomeClass.method_a() appends values to the list in this class."""

    def __init__(self):
        self.result_list = []
```

This way each instance of `ResultContainer` has its own instance of `result_list` whereas before all instances of `ResultContainer` would share the same `result_list`. With this change in place your tests work flawlessly:

```
$ python -m pytest tests
========================== test session starts ===========================
platform darwin -- Python 3.6.5, pytest-6.1.0, py-1.9.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /Users/oschlueter/github/pytest_test
collected 2 items                                                        

tests/test_method_a.py ..                                          [100%]

=========================== 2 passed in 0.01s ============================
```